# Passive capillary wick samplers

Tags: soil-moisture, soil-science

I am interested in sampling soil solution at different depths on Andean soils. I have found that Passive-capillary samplers have been extensively used to sample soil water, however I was not able to find a specific design methodology. Does anyone has knowledge about this technique or can recommend some bibliography?